# QStandardItemModel - add a row with only one item

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

MRE:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import PyQt5
import sys, types

class OrgItemModel( QStandardItemModel ):
    def __init__( self, tree_view ):
        super().__init__()
        self.tree_view = tree_view
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels( [ 'Tasks', 'Due date', 'Notes' ] )

def configure( tree_view, main_window ):
    tree_view.setModel( OrgItemModel( tree_view ) )
    def load_from_list( self ):
        new_model = OrgItemModel( self )
        root_item = new_model.invisibleRootItem()
        lines = [
            'Europe ||| 2020-10-26 ||| some notes',
            '==France ||| 2020-10-27 ||| some France notes',
            '====Paris ||| --- ||| blah blah',
            '==Germany |||  ||| ',
            '==Italy ||| 2020-10-28 ||| some Italy notes',
            '====Rome |||  ||| ',
            '==Ireland ||| 2020-10-30 ||| blah blah',
        ]
        new_model.ptr = 0
        def read_child_rows( item, depth = 0 ):        
            while new_model.ptr < len( lines ):
                line = lines[ new_model.ptr ]
                new_model.ptr += 1  
                n_equals = len( line ) - len( line.lstrip('=') )
                item_text = line.lstrip('=').strip()
                read_depth = n_equals / 2
                if read_depth == depth:
                    item_col0 = QStandardItem( item_text )
                    # split up the line by the substring ' ||| '
                    item_texts = line.split( ' ||| ' )
                    text_col0 = item_texts[ 0 ].lstrip( '=' ).strip()
                    text_col1 = item_texts[ 1 ].strip()
                    text_col2 = item_texts[ 2 ].strip()
                    item_col0 = QStandardItem( text_col0 )    
                    if text_col1 == '':
                        print( f'col1 blank for {text_col0}')
                        item_col1 = None
                    else:
                        item_col1 = QStandardItem( text_col1 )    
                    if text_col2 == '':
                        print( f'col2 blank for {text_col0}')
                        item_col2 = None
                    else:
                        item_col2 = QStandardItem( text_col2 )    
                    if item_col1 == None or item_col2 == None:
                        print( 'inserting just first item...')
                        item.appendRow( item_col0 )
                    else:  
                        item.appendRow( [ item_col0, item_col1, item_col2 ] )
                    # NB here I'm trying to examine the row which has just been added.
                    # But this is now not giving the right value for rowCount: this
                    # may be because previously I was experimenting with new_model.appendRow 
                    # rather than item.appendRow: the central problem still arises...
                    print( f'row count {new_model.rowCount()}')    
                    for j_col in range( 3 ):
                        index = new_model.index( new_model.rowCount() - 1, j_col )
                        data_at_coord = new_model.data( index )
                        print( data_at_coord, index.isValid() )
                else:
                    new_model.ptr -= 1
                    if read_depth > depth:
                        read_child_rows( item_col0, depth + 1 )
                    else:
                        break
        read_child_rows( root_item )
        del new_model.ptr
        self.setModel( new_model )
        self.expandAll()
        self.resizeColumnToContents( 0 )
    tree_view.load_from_list = types.MethodType( load_from_list, tree_view )

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(1100, 580)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.treeView = QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 1000, 320 ))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

class MyWindow( QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super( MyWindow, self ).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        configure( self.ui.treeView, self )
        self.ui.treeView.load_from_list()

app = QApplication([])
application = MyWindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I'm puzzled by the `QStandardItemModel` methods `insertRow` and `appendRow`. At the moment I have a `QTreeView` with 3 columns in the model. I am iterating through a list to reconstitute the tree, based on indentation in the list (using "==" at the start of the line per depth level) to represent the tree depth.

Each line in the list separates the texts of the three items on a given row with a string " ||| " (I plan to implement JSON serialisation at some point).

When I split the line text on " ||| " this produces 3 strings. If the second or third is a blank string this should mean that this item should not be added to the model, i.e. in the tree view one should see just the tree node, and the rest of its row should contain no items (i.e. invalid indices).
... but I find that even if I insert with just 1 item (rather than a list of 3 items), three items are (sometimes) created in the row in the `QTreeView`'s model. And `index.isValid()` in the checking lines above always returns `True`, even when it's just inserted one item (in col0). In such a case, `data_at_coord` for col1 and col2 is printed as "None".

And, thus, in the view when displayed, I can click on col1 or col2 for the row where I have done this, and find a blank editable item, and on examination find that these are valid indices. They shouldn't be: my intention is to add a new row where there are no items in col1 and col2, only in col0.

When I run the above MRE, **the "Rome" row behaves as it should**: you can try clicking on col1 and col2, but nothing happens. **But the "Germany" row seems to behave oddly**: when I click on col1 or col2 I find I am editing a blank string.

NB if in fact you use `new_model.appendRow` rather than `item.appendRow` there is a difference in terms of result:

1. the tree construction algorithm doesn't work as it's meant to and
2. the "Rome" row also now fails to do what it "should", and col1 and col2 are editable blank strings.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I understand, but as I say, it would be rather huge. Working on it... (I'm a PyQt5 newb, so it could take some time to cut things down to a manageable size...)

Comment: I don't understand why users with experience on the site (as their 8k shows) expect to be asked for an MRE if clearly posts of that type require it. You should have taken the time it takes to build the MRE before asking the question.

Comment: It may be that Python people expect an MRE more systematically than in the Java world. My initial hope with a question like this is that it turns out to be a known issue and someone can just recognise it. I find the documentation for QTreeView, both in Python and C++, pretty incomplete, so much knowledge may just be residing in users' heads.

Comment: Here the language or the subcommunities around them are not interested since their problem can be summarized as: I want to do X, try to do Y but it does not work, how can I solve it?, Then on the other side we ask ourselves: What would have failed in Y ? Well we are going to execute Y to analyze and understand the error, but at the post we cannot see how to reproduce the error since there is no MRE.

Comment: SO is not a place where you flip a coin and hopefully someone catches it, here we have a guide on how to ask and how to answer.

Comment: Point taken and suitably chastised. As I say I'm working on it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not caused by the appendRow method but by undocumented behavior. It seems that with the tree type models all the nodes always have the same number of columns except the nodes that do not have children generating this unexpected behavior. A workaround is that in text items it is to create QStandardItem with the Qt::NoItemFlags flag so that the user cannot interact with them:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeView, QWidget


class OrgItemModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Tasks", "Due date", "Notes"])


def configure_from_list(model, lines):
    def get_parent_item(depth):
        parent = model.invisibleRootItem()
        if depth == 0:
            return parent
        for _ in range(depth):
            if parent.hasChildren():
                parent = parent.child(parent.rowCount() - 1)
            else:
                it = QStandardItem()
                it.setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags)
                parent.appendRow(it)
                parent = it
        return parent

    for line in lines:
        values = line.strip("=")
        depth = (len(line) - len(values)) // 2
        items = []
        for value in values.split("|||"):
            text = value.strip()
            item = QStandardItem()
            if text:
                item.setText(text)
            else:
                item.setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags)
            items.append(item)
        parent_item = get_parent_item(depth)
        parent_item.appendRow(items)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(1100, 580)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.treeView = QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 1000, 320))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        lines = [
            "Europe ||| 2020-10-26 ||| some notes",
            "==France ||| 2020-10-27 ||| some France notes",
            "====Paris ||| --- ||| blah blah",
            "==Germany |||  ||| ",
            "==Italy ||| 2020-10-28 ||| some Italy notes",
            "====Rome |||  ||| ",
            "==Ireland ||| 2020-10-30 ||| blah blah",
        ]
        model = OrgItemModel()
        self.ui.treeView.setModel(model)
        configure_from_list(model, lines)
        self.ui.treeView.expandAll()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
application = MyWindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to analyse this. I find it quite surprising that a mature project like PyQt5 should harbour such undocumented behaviour, to which no-one appears to have drawn attention before now, but obviously I am new to PyQt5 so not in a position to judge such matters.